# What is wrong with this code when i sort only a portion of an array not starting from index 0?

Tags: java, mergesort

When I use `mergeSort` to sort a portion of an array it gives `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` but if I merge a portion starting from the index 0 to any other index it works why?

```
public static void mergeSort(int[] arr, int[] temp, int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        
        mergeSort(arr, temp, low, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, temp, mid + 1, high);
        merge(arr, temp, low, mid, high);
    }
}

public static void merge(int[] arr, int[] temp, int low, int mid, int high) {

    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
        temp[i] = arr[i];
    }
    
    int i = low;
    int j = mid + 1; 
    int k = low;
    
    while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
        if (temp[i] <= temp[j]) {
            arr[k] = temp[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            arr[k] = temp[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i <= mid) {
        arr[k] = temp[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
}
```

I get an error `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

The argument `high` in your code is the index of the last element in the slice to be sorted or merged. Are you sure you pass `array.length - 1` as the last argument to the topmost call to `mergeSort()`?

Also make sure you allocate the `temp` array with the same length as the array to be sorted.

This convention is confusing and does not allow for empty arrays. You might instead use a more idiomatic convention where `high` is the index of the element after the last one and you pass `array.length` to the topmost call.

Here is a modified version:

```
public static void mergeSort(int[] arr, int[] temp, int low, int high) {
    if (high - low > 1) {
        int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        mergeSort(arr, temp, low, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, temp, mid, high);
        merge(arr, temp, low, mid, high);
    }
}

public static void merge(int[] arr, int[] temp, int low, int mid, int high) {

    for (int i = low; i < high; i++) {
        temp[i] = arr[i];
    }
    
    int i = low;
    int j = mid; 
    int k = low;
    
    while (i < mid && j < high) {
        if (temp[i] <= temp[j]) {
            arr[k++] = temp[i++];
        } else {
            arr[k++] = temp[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < mid) {
        arr[k++] = temp[i++];
    }
}
```